# Transparent div over canvas leaves darker area only if filling red color

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

Im having as background a canvas, filled with the video taken from html camera.

Over that background, two divs are drawn, and whether to drawn one or another is chosen by sorting a random number. Doing that, the overlay divs are constantly changing.

Both of those divs are 60% transparent, one is red and the other is green.

The amazing thing that I can't help to understand is, the red div leaves a darker patch on the canvas than the green one.

If I change the red div to blue, then the darker patch disappears.

I would be thanked if somebody helps me with this mystery.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rgZLEW

The red or green divs are toogled like this:

```
function draw_green(){
  $('.preloader').hide();
  $('.green').show();
 }
function draw_red() {
  $('.preloader').hide();
  $('.red').show();
 }
```

And the divs are just:

```
<div class="main-wrapper"> 
  <div class="preloader green" style="display: none">
     <div class="loader-container">
        <div>
          <div class="text-logo">Green</div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="preloader red" style="display: none">
    <div class="loader-container">
      <div>
        <div class="text-logo">Red</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <canvas></canvas>
```

The canvas is drawn inside the loop function:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
            stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {

              if (track.kind == 'video')
                      document.getElementById('video').srcObject = stream;
                  startLoop();
            });
        }, function(err) {
            alert('Could not acquire media: ' + err);
        });


    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var video =  document.querySelector('video');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      var loopFrame = false;
      function loop(){
        loopFrame = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width,   canvas.height);
        ctx.restore();
      }

      function startLoop(){
        loopFrame = loopFrame || requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      }
```

[image: patch]

Comment: What do you call a "patch" here? Can you take a screenshot of what you see? Or are you only talking about the [Purkinje effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purkinje_effect) in which case your question is absolutely not about programming...

Comment: picture addedddd

Comment: ok thanks. What browser are you experiencing it with, what OS? I can't repro on my macOS

Comment: Chrome Version 74.0.3729.108,Ubuntu 16.04. You see the webcam working ,but you dont get the patch?

Comment: Yes exactly. Works fine for me (no patch) on FF, Chrome and Safari/

Comment: Not happening on chrome on android, now that I check it.